# Como compilar vários arquivos python em um só usando Pyinstaller?

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

Estou fazendo um programa de cálculo que está dividido em 3 arquivos `py`:

- arquivo da  interface gráfica (`cerberus.py`)
- arquivo que procede os cálculos(`calc.py`)
- arquivo responsável pela plotagem dos dados(`plot.py`)

Tentei compilar com o comando:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed cerberus.py
```

Mas ao abrir o arquivo resultante, ele não procedia mais os cálculos nem as plotagens no canvas, estava "`inerte`". Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score -1):

Para "puxar" outros módulos ao seu arquivo executável tente usar o seguinte código, lembrando que os outros arquivos devem estar na mesma pasta que seu arquivo principal, no mesmo nível :

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. --onefile --windowed cerberus.py
```